# Few general questions about "org.eclipse.wst.server.core" folder of a web application in Java

Tags: java, glassfish, temporary-files

I have a few questions regarding the **org.eclipse.wst.server.core** folder in `.metadata\.plugins` folder in a eclipse work space. I know that while running an application in local host, this is the folder where we have to replace files for front end, like `JSP`, `JS` files, `CSS` files, `HTML` files, `Images` etc.

There will be some `tmp` folders into which I have to replace the files into respective locations. This folder will be having another folder with structure of a `WAR` file which I'll take from my work space and sometimes there will be multiple `tmp` folders like `tmp0`, `tmp1`, `tmp2` etc (most of them having all required files). When there are multiple folders it is really confusing to decide that into which folder I need to replace the file(s).

[image]

Then I'll have to stop the server, kill all the `java` running in background (manually) and have to clear all the `tmp` folders (because if the java is not killed properly the `jar` files inside `tmp`'s cannot be deleted saying its currently being used). I guess one among these `tmp` folders are used by the server to run the application.

After cleaning all the `tmp` folders if I start the server again, the first file created in that folder (**org.eclipse.wst.server.core**) will be one `servers.xml`, then one `tmp0` will be created may be `tmp1`. When entire project is published only one `tmp` folder will be there, if I publish multiple times, another `tmp` folder will be created, may be 2nd time, 3rd time or nth time.

**So my questions are**

1. Is there a general name for **org.eclipse.wst.server.core** folder?
2. Why multiple `tmp` folders are created when publised multiple times? Can we restrict it into a single `tmp` folder?
3. After the project is published, is there a possibility that server will use multiple `tmp` folders for different request. Like for first request I uses `tmp0` and when I refresh the page it uses `tmp1` folder?

**Edited regarding the 3rd question**

I opened all the `xml` files in the folder given in the above image, and in `tmp-data.xml`, I found this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<temp-directories>
  <temp-directory age="0" key="GlassFish v2.1 Java EE 5 at localhost" path="tmp0"/>
</temp-directories>
```

Where `path` attribute is given value as `tmp0`. So I'm guessing that will be the answer to my third question. I'm guessing this file will be created when there are multiple `tmp` folders, because after deleting all `tmp` folders and files in the folder and after publishing the work space the `tmp-data.xml` file was not present.

**Edited regarding the WTP**

I don't have much details about WTP, but when I clicked `Help` and selected `About Eclipse` in my eclipse I got this window

[image]

Comment: What eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Galileo

Comment: I think the folder which is currently used for running the application will be specified in **tmp-data.xml**. Anything about my first and fourth question

Answer (score 1):

1. Not that I know of. It is created by WTP (Web Tools Platform) using WST (Web Standard Tools). If you find, let me know too.
2. That depends upon different checks that WTP and WST do before publishing the artifacts. It does not happen all the time, but it does a lot more than expected, because of file locks that stop eclipse from publishing a fresh copy of the application. And hence, the code must be trying to create new tmp folder just as a workaround. The metadata (publish.xml) is then updated, and everything works as normal, which I feel is much better since the developer does not have to know a lot of stuff about these failures. We can change this setting in the server properties in your eclipse. Note that different plugins have different ways of doing this, my STS has default deploy path set to wtpwebapps.
3. This must be available in your publish xml file. And it also depends upon the version of WTP / WST you are using. It is hard to see where the folder generation is happening (at least for me at this time), but you can look at PublishUtils.java and PublishDelegate.java in WTP. [Github here](https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.servertools/tree/master/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/servercore/org/eclipse/wst/server/core/model).
4. No certainly not, after a project is published the whole server points to the location at which the artifacts reside. Though the context refresh might fail because of overlapping threads or wait time, it is not possible for two different instances to be deployed into the same server with the same application/context name.

Read [this](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/main.php) and [this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-change-default-webapp)

Comment: I've made some edits to the question, might be a possible answer to the third question.

Comment: Only one and its Glassfish.

Comment: I cannot find much in github for this, I will have to clone and see, but why would you want to know how the folders are generated? The latest folder is in publish.xml, wouldnt that be enough?